# How do I programmatically load a specified sales rule in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, rules

In Magento 1 EE, I was able to get sales rule information from product list page with the following:

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($ruleId);
$isActive = $rule->getIsActive(); 
$fromDate = $rule->getFromDate();
$toDate = $rule->getToDate();
$label = $rule->getStoreLabel();
```

How can I accomplish the same thing in Magento 2?

Comment: How about your current issue?

Comment: I tried the examples today without any luck. I did find a solution, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to go about it. See below...

Answer (score 3):

We can try:

```
/** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $rule **/
$rule->load($ruleId);
$isActive = $rule->getIsActive(); 
$fromDate = $rule->getFromDate();
$toDate = $rule->getToDate();
$label = $rule->getStoreLabels();
```

Or with API:

```
/** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface $rule **/
$rule->getById($ruleId);
$isActive = $rule->getIsActive(); 
$fromDate = $rule->getFromDate();
$toDate = $rule->getToDate();
$label = $rule->getStoreLabels();
```

Remember to inject `\Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface` or `\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule` on your constructor.

```
/** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface $rule **/

protected $rule;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface $rule

) {

   $this->rule = $rule;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This seemed to work for me, but I'm not sure it's exactly the way it should be handled or not. Open to suggestions. Thanks.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$rule = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule')->load($ruleId);
$isActive = $rule->getIsActive();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my answer works well. We need to inject the sale rule model in your constructor.

Comment: How do I inject the constructor? Thanks.

Comment: See my update answer.